# Coding data for a nested fixed effect in a GLMM in R

Tags: r, lme4

I would like include nested fixed effect in my general linear mixed model. We have three datasets and two are related to each other. Currently we ran it as a three level predictor variable neglecting the relation between two of them. We would like to know how to implement this relation but we don't know what the call is and we don't know how to code the data. We are using R and the glmer package. Please advise.

```
$ id : Factor w/ 66 levels 
$ item : Factor w/ 135 levels 
$ correct : Factor w/ 2 levels 
$ dataset : Factor w/ 3 levels A, B, C 
$ emotion : Factor w/ 5 levels
```

The current call is:

```
correct ~ ( 1 | ID) + (1 | item) + emotion + dataset
```

The data is coded as: dataset A B C

How do we show that A and B are related?

We have tried coding the relationship as (A and B are members of X):

```
x$dataset x$dataset2
A X
B X
C Y
```

We tried

```
correct ~ dataset2/dataset + emotion + (1|ID) + (1|item)
```

but we do not know whether this is correct and how to interpret the results.